# Image_tag in Ruby on Rails allows me to change the "Size" parameter but not "height/width" parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Problem**: I am currently doing an assignment for a Ruby on Rails course in which I need to pull information from the Coursera API and display it in an organized table. The exact problem is the pictures in their database is huge, so I was forced to resize it inside the image_tag. I was having trouble because "height" and "width" parameters were giving me syntax errors, so I tried the "size" parameter with the same syntax and it worked!

Original line of code:

```
<td><%= image_tag(course["photoUrl"])%></td>
```

Which pulled the photo without a problem from the course Hash.

**Working code** with fixed size:

```
<td><%= image_tag(course["photoUrl"], size: "250")%></td>
```

Which indeed, fixed the size of the image quite nicely.

Code that I don't understand why it does **not work**:

```
<td><%= image_tag(course["photoUrl"], height: "250" width: "350")%></td>
```

**Documentation:** http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just missing a comma (`,`) between the width and height parameters.

```
<td><%= image_tag(course["photoUrl"], width: "350", height: "250")%></td>
```

Alternatively, you could still use the size attribute like so:

```
<td><%= image_tag(course["photoUrl"], size: "350x250")%></td>
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that. I enjoy the change to the size parameter, gives it a little more syntactic sugar.